# adding div dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

i have this small todo application where in i have three div namely production,development and testing and inside those i have subtasks which have p id="subtask".

Now here i have a add link in every task which will add new subtasks in the corresponding tasks div.So when ever i click on add,then a new p id="subtask" should get created below the previous subtasks.

I have addd an image of the task div consisting of subtask,i need new subtask to be created
below the previous ones.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACIiY.png

```
 <div class="user span9 default-skin">
<ul>
    <% if @project.tasks.any? %>
        <% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>

        <div class="span5" id="tasks">

            <p><b><%=task.taskname %></b>
            <%=link_to 'edit name',edit_task_path(task) %></p>

            <% task.subtasks.each do |subtask| %>


                <p id="subtask" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><%=subtask.name %></p>
                <%end%>

                <%=render 'layouts/modal' %>

                <p id="addcard"><a href="#">Add a card...</a></p>
        </div>

    <%end%>
<%end%>


</ul>


</div>
```

and here is the jquery that i tried

```
$("#addcard > a").click(function(){
    $("#subtask").append("<p id='subtask'></p>");
  });
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: its in rails,so it consists a lot of ruby code as well.Basically a div id="tasks" is used for tasks like production,developement and testing,and each of these tasks have subtasks as p id="subtask",as u can c in the image.i have attached the pic of the devlopemnt task with the "second sub task" and "my second sub task" being the sub-tasks of this task.so when i click on the add card another p id="subtask" should get created.This is wat i want

Comment: you need to share the generated html and the script that you have already

Comment: i have added the code,you can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i have don't have the code

So will explain you this will an example

```
 Your html


  <div id='production'></div>
  <input type='button' value='Add' id='add_production'/>

your jquery
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#add_production').click(function(){
 $('#production').append('<p>Sub Task</p>');
   });
  });
```

Comment: you should not append paragraph to paragraph

Comment: sanjeev,dis append cant it append the new subtask before the add card button,right now its appending below it.

Comment: add a <div id='dynamic_element'> </div> where ever you want to add element & then use this id to add the div

Comment: now the issues is that since i hav a add card button for every task that i have.I want the new subtask to be added to only that task whose add to card button i have clicked

Comment: sanjeev,can u suggest somethin related to this issue.Some jquery which appends the content only in its parent container from which the add card button was clicked